# Can I use a DateComponentsFormatter to render the time of day?

Tags: swift, nsdatecomponentsformatter

I would like to store a time of day in a simple way. For the purposes of my app, I only care about a specific time of day, like 2:30pm or 1:10am.

Using a `DateComponentsFormatter` I can get really close.

```
import Foundation

let formatter = DateComponentsFormatter()
formatter.unitsStyle = .positional
formatter.allowedUnits = [
    .hour,
    .minute
]
 
// Use the configured formatter to generate the string.
let timeAmount = 9000.0
let outputString = formatter.string(from: timeAmount)
let desiredString = "2:30 pm"import Foundation

let formatter = DateComponentsFormatter()
formatter.unitsStyle = .positional
formatter.allowedUnits = [
    .hour,
    .minute
]
 
// Use the configured formatter to generate the string.
let timeAmount = 9000.0
let outputString = formatter.string(from: timeAmount) // yields "2:30"
let desiredString = "2:30 pm"
```

Now, it seems that the formatter is really just saying "two hours and thirty minutes," so maybe I am barking up the wrong tree here. Does `DateComponentsFormatter` support my use case?

Comment: The `DateComponentsFormatter` is for expressing the amount of time between two dates. `DateFormatter` is for formatting dates or times. Use `DateFormatter`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `DateComponentsFormatter` is for expressing the amount of time between two dates. `DateFormatter` is for formatting dates or times. Use `DateFormatter`.

If your intent is to display a time in the UI, use `DateFormatter`, but

- Do not use `dateFormat`, but rather use `timeStyle`;
- Do not override `locale`;
- Do not set `timeZone`;

E.g. to show the current time in the UI:

```
let date = Date()
let formatter = DateFormatter()
formatter.timeStyle = .short
let string = formatter.string(from: date)
```

By the way, this will format time strings as preferred by the user (e.g. AM/PM for some of us, but in other locales, users may prefer 24 hour clock representation). When displaying information in the UI, we should always honor the user’s preferences.

---

If you’re trying to convert your 9,000 seconds to 2:30am:

```
let startOfDay = Calendar.current.startOfDay(for: Date())
let date = startOfDay.addingTimeInterval(9000)

let formatter = DateFormatter()
formatter.timeStyle = .short
let string = formatter.string(from: date)    // 2:30 AM
```

Clearly, if you happen to be on a date where you are shifting to or from daylight savings, your result may vary.

Answer (score 2):

From the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/datecomponentsformatter):

> An `DateComponentsFormatter` object takes quantities of time and formats them as a user-readable string.

The point is that a `DateComponentsFormatter` operates on *quantities of time* (e.g. 2 hours and 10 minutes), whereas you want a *point* in time. These are very different things. Trying to use `DateComponentsFormatter` to produce a time of day could work if you try hard enough, it's just that you are misusing/abusing it.

It seems like you are storing the times of day as the number of seconds since midnight. To format this with `DateComponentsFormatter`, you would need to do a lot of checks and calculations with the stored number:

- You need to add the am/pm string yourself.
- You need to add 12 hours to any time that's below 1 hour.
- You need to subtract 12 hours when the stored time is greater than 12 hours.
- There's probably more that you need to consider that I missed

Plus, the am/pm is not localisable. There also might be some cultures in the world where they use a different format to display quantities of time from times of day (I don't know!), which will cause this approach to break down completely.

---

`DateFormatter` should be used to format times of day. Just add the stored time to the UNIX epoch time (or any other midnight) and format with the UTC timezone:

```
let formatter = DateFormatter()
formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
formatter.dateFormat = "hh:mm a"
// or you can replace the above 2 lines with something more localised:
// formatter.timeStyle = .short
formatter.timeZone = TimeZone(identifier: "UTC")
let output = formatter.string(from: Date(timeIntervalSince1970: storedTime))
```

Comment: You should always set the date formatter’s locale to en_US_POSIX before setting the dateFormat when using a fixed date format.

Comment: **You should first set the locale of the date formatter to something appropriate for your fixed format. In most cases the best locale to choose is "en_US_POSIX", a locale that's specifically designed to yield US English results regardless of both user and system preferences.**

Comment: IMO you should always use date and time style instead of a fixed date format when displaying date/time to the user. When storing minutes and/or hours  better to store it as integers.

Comment: @LeoDabus Edited. I kept the fixed format. I didn't want to question the premise too much. The question was about `DateComponentsFormatter` after all, and not `DateFormatter` :-)